# How do react-css-modules (babel) and css-loader (webpack) work together?

Tags: babeljs, webpack-5, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

When using webpack and babel together, one needs to configure both in order to use React CSS Modules. For example:

`webpack.config.js` will need a rule like this:

```js
{
  // Translates CSS into CommonJS modules
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    modules: {
      mode: "local",
      localIdentName: CSS_CLASS_NAME_PATTERN,
    },
  sourceMap: true
}
```

`babel.config.js` will need a plugin like this:

```js
[
  'react-css-modules',
  {
    generateScopedName: CSS_CLASS_NAME_PATTERN,
    filetypes: {
      '.scss': {
        syntax: 'postcss-scss',
        plugins: ['postcss-nested']
      }
    },
  }
]
```

Why the need to configure CSS Modules in two places? How the two work together? I.e. what happens in what order?

Answer (score 6):

They don't. `css-loader` does its own thing: class name transformation in CSS, and replacement of CSS imports in JS code by mappings between original and generated names.

`babel-plugin-react-css-modules` works independently, and it replaces `styleName` attributes of react components by `className` with correct generated names. To do so it calculates class name mappings independently from `css-loader`, that's why it needs separate configuration matching that of `css-loader`, and that's why after a few years being abandoned by its creators it has compatibility issues with latest `css-loader` (css-loader changed internal class name generation logic).

Shameless self-promo: I maintain an [up-to-date fork of `babel-plugin-react-css-modules`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules) which solves compatibility issues with  latest `css-loader` versions.

Comment: Why not send a PR into the poorly maintained original repo? The current maintainer reviews PRs from my recent experience.

Comment: Nah... the original plugin lost its compatibility with `css-loader` in August 2020, with release of `css-loader@4.0.0`, and it took the "maintainer" four months even to comment on the thread where it was reported: https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/issues/291

It took me just a few days to fork, fix, and release my own version ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There's been no more releases of the old version since May 2019 so I'll be trying this.