# Migrating from Webpack v4 to v5. Styling not picked up

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I've migrated Webpack to v5 in my React project and none of my .scss files are picked up when I run it

I've followed this guide on migrating webpack https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/ updated all plugins and loaders (all of them are MAJOR updates) that I use in development mode, updated configuration file to accommodate new versions but none of the styles are applied

My package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^10.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    ...
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.2.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    ...
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    ...
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.6",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.6.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
  "sideEffects": [
    "*.css",
    "*.scss"
  ]
}
```

My webpack.config.json:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    path: outPath,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    globalObject: 'this'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: [
          /(node_modules)/,
          /\.test.tsx?$/,
          /\.spec.tsx?$/
        ],
        use: [
          {loader: 'react-hot-loader/webpack'},
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
              allowTsInNodeModules: false,
              onlyCompileBundledFiles: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          {loader: 'style-loader'},
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

This is how I import styles in my modules:

```
const styles = require('./index.scss')

<div className={styles['some-class']}>
```

When I was on previous webpack version everything worked fine, but as soon as I upgraded webpack and all the webpack related packages, styling is no longer applied.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `require` and not `import`, you have to specify `default`:

```
const styles = require('./index.scss').default;
```

Comment: As you can see from my webpack.config.js I already do have modules, setting it to an object already enables CSS modules for all files, as it is specified in the documentation. I did try `modules: true` as well same problem

Comment: @NickiEvans Alright, I missed that. What do you have if you `console.log(styles)` ? `undefined`?

Comment: I have added screenshot of what I get if I console.log(styles), its not undefined actually, but accessing classname is giving undefined? @Arkellys

Comment: @NickiEvans Ah yes I see the problem, I will update my answer.

Comment: yeah I realized, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74184207/1137085) would solve my issue, but unfortunately (fortunately?) I wasn't using `require`.

I found that the project I was working on was using [`gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules`](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules), which has an [open issue](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/issues/301) since April 2021, suggesting that the "[contenthash] generated by this plugin does not match the hash generated by css-loader 5.2.0". A [comment in that issue](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/issues/301#issuecomment-1377919816) directed me to [this comment](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/pull/303#issuecomment-846760495) that suggested using a fork (as the original plugin appears to be unmaintained) and linked to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67173238/how-do-react-css-modules-babel-and-css-loader-webpack-work-together/67241915#67241915) which explains:

> [..snip..]and that's why after a few years being abandoned by its creators it has compatibility issues with latest `css-loader` (`css-loader` changed internal class name generation logic).

That StackOverflow answer also linked to an updated/supposedly maintained fork:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules
- https://github.com/birdofpreyru/babel-plugin-react-css-modules

  - https://github.com/birdofpreyru/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#installation
  - https://github.com/birdofpreyru/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#project-history

    - > This plugin is an up-to-date, well-maintained fork of the original babel-plugin-react-css-modules:
    - > The original `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` plugin is largely abandoned by its author since March 2019. When an year later updates of `css-loader` and Webpack broke dependant projects, with no reaction from `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` author on emerging issue reports in GitHub, I ([`birdofpreyru`](https://github.com/birdofpreyru)) created this fork to ensure stability of my own projects relying on it.
  - https://github.com/birdofpreyru/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#css-loader-compatibility

After making the changes required to switch to the new forked plugin, CSS module sources came through successfully in my Webpack v5 build!

Comment: Awesome, nice find!